# Creating a stacked graph in Adobe Illustrator with alternating colours

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I aim to create an interleaving style of stacked graph of black/white/black pattern in illustrator.Like a DNA profile or a variable length bar code.

Currently the values defaults to shades of grey. When i try to replace colour it doesnt work as effectively as i need it to change.

[image: Current Artifact generated automatically.]

Comment: What method are you using in trying to "replace color"?

Comment: Try using a gradient. You can have many colors inside a gradient. And you can disable the flow so the colors fo not mix. But i personally think that the method which @Billy Kerr described here is more useful in this situation

Comment: So you want to generate large images which contain barcode-like stripes of alterating width and color which you need to adjust often and easily? My first guess would be to write a program which generates SVG images in the style you want. Alternatively if this is really important to you and you don't have the skills yourself then maybe hire a freelancer or something to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Direct Selection tool (A) to select one of the parts of the graph,
and then apply a fill to it.

[image: Screenshot of Graph being filled with colour]

Comment: i have at the moment 85 elements, to do this manually would be extremely difficult. I may have even more in the future

Comment: So, once you have coloured it once, you can use the graph again by copying and pasting it, and just change the data. The colours you chose will stick.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't scale for me..  [link](http://i.imgur.com/BGerA5u.png) here is at an attempt at the method

Comment: it works till exactly the number of patterns i set if i set 30 patterns the new copy will repeat / use the pattern till 30, anything beyond 30 it tends to go on its own agenda of colouring

Answer (score 0):

Try Gradient map.

1. On the layers panel, use the circle icon, add a new layer, a Gradient Map.

2-3. And then choose or prepare your color scheme.

What it is going to happen is that the gray levels will be changed to a color defined in the new gradient.

[image]